# Tuple index out of range in string formatting

Tags: python

I have a tuple:

```
('ORF eins', '20:15', '21:05', 'soko-donau.html', 'Soko Donau', 'Schöne neue Welt')
```

that has six elements (index 0-5).

If I print with string formatting, like this:

```
print("""Entry {}
Title: {}
Station: {}
Start Time: {}
End Time: {}""".format(programID, details[4], details[0], details[1]), details[2])
```

I get an "IndexError: tuple index out of range" although I only use the index until `4` and have 6 elements in my tuple.

Comment: @Abstracted there's no more readable way to create a multi-line string. If reserving `"""` for docstrings was important you'd expect [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to say something about it, unless it's there and I missed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a parenthesis in the wrong place:

```
print("""Entry {}
Title: {}
Station: {}
Start Time: {}
End Time: {}""".format(programID, details[4], details[0], details[1]), details[2])
#                                                                   ^
```

So your format statement is getting 4 arguments when it is expecting 5 (because there are 5 "substitution slots `{}`") so when it tries to get the 5th parameter, it has an `IndexError`.

You'll get the same thing with `"{}".format()` for example:

```
>>> "{}".format()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: saw it a few minutes after i posted it, works perfectly fine now of course :D thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You have a closing bracket after `details[1]` which messes up your code.